# 'key' in vs object.key

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Is there any difference between:

```
if('mykey' in obj){

}
```

and

```
if(obj.mykey){

}
```

?

Comment: will be the version of javascript is using the navigator. The second is more standard for older navigators

Comment: you can test and see the difference here => https://jsfiddle.net/hmck56ct/

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have

```
var obj = { mykey: false };
```

Then `'mykey' in obj` will be `true`, while `obj.mykey` will be `false`. A very big difference.

The `'mykey' in obj` expression will check if the object have a property or not. The `obj.mykey` expression will retrieve the value of the property and use that.

Also, if the object `obj` doesn't have a `mykey` property, then `'mykey' in obj` will result in `false` while `obj.mykey` result in *`undefined`*.

Comment: what if mykey is a empty object? will obj.mykey still return false?

Comment: @yomamma No, an empty object will evaluate as `true` -> [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) / [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values

Comment: Since he's using it in `if()`, both `false` and `undefined` will have the same result.

Comment: @Barmar Yes the end result if (and only if) `mykey` isn't a property of `obj` will be the same if the way the they are used by the OP. There's still a very big semantic difference.

Comment: Often you know a priori that if a property exists it will have a truthy value, so `obj.property` can be used instead of `"property" in obj`. This is common in certain idioms, e.g. `xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`

Answer (score 0):

```
if('mykey' in obj){

}
```

In the above case mkey is type of object say "Car" in "obj-Car" list

whereas

```
 if(obj.mykey){

}
```

In the above you have mkey as property as "Engine" of object 'obj-Car'

Answer (score 0):

`if ('mykey' in obj)` checks for existence of mykey property in obj.

`if (obj.mykey)` checks the value of mykey property in obj. The value could be undefined if the property doesn't exist, but it could also be null, false or empty string which will also evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are checking if `mykey` property **exists** in the object. In the second case, you are checking if `mykey` property of object is **false**, which includes being **null**, **undefined**, **zero** or even **empty**. So in the second case, if it exists, yet the value is **zero**, then the `if` statement won't get executed. In the first case it will, because it only checks if the property exists.

Example:

```
var obj = {"a": 1, "b": 0};

if ("b" in obj) { // gets executed }

if (obj.b) { // doesn't get executed }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {
   mykey: true

}

if('mykey' in obj){
   //checks if the object has this key
   //true
}


if(obj.mykey){
   //check if object key's value is 'true'
   //true
}
```

whereas

```
let obj = {
   mykey: false

}

if('mykey' in obj){
   //checks if the object has this key
   //true
}


if(obj.mykey){
   //check if object key's value is 'true'
   //false
}
```